# Leaving sourced shell script without exiting terminal

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm writing a shell script to save some key strokes and avoid typos.  I would like to keep the script as a single file that calls internal methods/functions and terminates the functions if problems arise **without** leaving the terminal.

**my_script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
exit_if_no_git() {
  # if no git directory found, exit
  # ...
  exit 1
}

branch() {
  exit_if_no_git
  # some code...
}

push() {
  exit_if_no_git
  # some code...
}

feature() {
  exit_if_no_git
  # some code...
}

bug() {
  exit_if_no_git
  # some code...
}
```

I would like to call it via:

```
$ branch
$ feature
$ bug
$ ...
```

I know I can `source git_extensions.sh` in my `.bash_profile`, but when I execute one of the commands and there is no `.git` directory, it will `exit 1` as expected but this also exits out of the terminal itself (since it's sourced).

Is there an alternative to `exit`ing the functions, which also exits the terminal?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `exit`? If you wrote your functions to start with something like `has_git_dir || return`, that would avoid the problem. Similarly, you can use `return` to leave a sourced script early.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for! I didn't want to use EXIT per se, but the only other "exiting" command I knew was BREAK and that isn't supposed to be used for exiting non-looping items. In my quick tests, using RETURN as you recommended allowed me to control workflow in my script. If you want to change the comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I updated the question with the underlying technical question and accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: A much better question now; it has my upvote (and close retracted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining a function `exit_if_no_git`, define one as `has_git_dir`:

```
has_git_dir() {
  local dir=${1:-$PWD}             # allow optional argument
  while [[ $dir = */* ]]; do       # while not at root...
    [[ -d $dir/.git ]] && return 0 # ...if a .git exists, return success
    dir=${dir%/*}                  # ...otherwise trim the last element
  done
  return 1                         # if nothing was found, return failure
}
```

...and, elsewhere:

```
branch() {
  has_git_dir || return
  # ...actual logic here...
}
```

That way the functions are short-circuited, but no shell-level exit occurs.

---

It's also possible to exit a file being `source`d using `return`, preventing later functions within it from even being defined, if `return` is run at top-level within such a file.